# C# Ошибка при перемещении файла из каталога в каталог

Tags: c#

Написал службу Windows, которая при попадании в определенную папку файлов копирует их в архив и потом перемещает в другой каталог для последующей обработки. Периодически в логах вижу ошибку Could not find file 'D:\OUT\A22222.02'. При этом получается: копирование в архив проходит без ошибок, далее файл перемещается в каталог, а потом пытается еще раз его обработать и появляется вот такая ошибка. Попробовал добавить паузу перед копированием., переносом и после. Но не помогло.
вот кусок кода. Из-за чего может происходить данная проблема?

```
public class Transfer{

private string out = @"D:\out\";
private string arh_path = @"D:\arh\";
private string encrypt = @"D:\encrypt\";

public void MovePayFile(){

try
{
    FileInfo[] fi = new DirectoryInfo(output).GetFiles();

    foreach(FileInfo file in fi)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(arh_path, file.Name));
        sql.InsertToLog(output, arh_path, file.Name, "Копирование в архив OUT", conn);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(encrypt, file.Name));
        sql.InsertToLog(output, encrypt, file.Name, "Шифрация файла",conn);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
catch (System.IO.IOException msg)
    {
        sql.EventLog("Error, code 1000", msg.Message, conn);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Какие значения принимают `arh_path` и `encrypt`?

Comment: Имеется подозрение, что переменная ``encrypt`` написана с ошибкой

Comment: А мне может быть такого, что файл перемещается одним потоком, а другой в это время уже снова перебирает файлы в папке? Тогда первый его переместит, а второй успеет решить что тоже должен, но не найдет.

Comment: @V-Mor Поправил в коде, добавил значения. Это пути к каталогам.

Comment: @alladuh Не, все верно. Это переменные в которых записаны пути к каталогую\

Comment: @AndreySherman попробуйте добавить ``true`` в методе ``CopyTo()``. Он имеет перегруженую версию

Comment: Отладчиком проходили? Все переменные нужные значения принимают? Или это долго работающее приложение?

Comment: А у вас и не будет этот код нормально работать. После команды `MoveTo()` в исходной папке больше нет этого файла. Что собственно и пишет вам скрипт в логах. Вот описание команды [MoveTo](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.moveto?view=netframework-4.8). И кодировать собственно нечего будет. ИМХО.

Comment: @Rootware после выполнения команды MoveTo() выполняется команда записи логов, в которую передаются пути и имя файлов. Собственно переменные output и encrypt уже заполнены, и file.Name тоже имеет значение

Comment: @AndreySherman вы попробовали вызвать метод ``CopyTo()`` с перегрузкой?

Comment: @V-Mor отладчиком не проходил. Приложение работает всего 2 недели. Изначально тестировал руками сам подкладывал файлы, и служба отрабатывала без ошибок. И вот в этом месте периодически возникает такая ошибка. Например 10 файлов без ошибок переместится, а 2 с ошибкой.

Comment: @alladuh Пересобрал приложение, сейчас буду смотреть на поведение.

Comment: @AndreySherman А расширения у файла всегда из цифр? Корректно ли будет распознано расширение этого файла `D:\OUT\A22222.02`?

Comment: @AndreySherman я почему говорю про перегруженую версию. Вот на msdn указано, что если не указывать параметр ``true``, то исходный файл перезаписывать нельзя: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.copyto?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @alladuh к сожалению, это не помогло.  Само копирование нормально проходит. Т.е. эта ошибка происходит во время выполнения операции MoveTo(); Почему она пытается файл переместить два раза. Не понятно. По логам видно что файл переместился, и потом 2й раз еще раз пробует.

Comment: @V-Mor Да, расширения всегда из цифр